# Appropriate logic for this pattern

Tags: if-statement, logic

How do I print a pattern with number of rows is equal to number of stars such that if 1 star then 1 row of 1 star, 2 star then 2 rows of 2 stars and so on, provided with good logic?
Here's the output for the logic mentioned above

```
*
**
**
***
***
***
```

Answer (score 0):

using [mod](https://www.baeldung.com/modulo-java) operator you can get proper output.Java has one important arithmetical operator you may not be familiar with, %, also known as the modulus or remainder operator. The % operator returns the remainder of two numbers. For instance 10 % 3 is 1 because 10 divided by 3 leaves a remainder of 1. You can use % just as you might use any other more common operator like + or -.

I write code in java.

Execution Steps:-

1. for loop for declare i value to 1.loop start with value 1 and last value 5.
2. for loop for declare i value to 1.in this we gave condition for j is i*i.
3. if j value is 1 then it print star.
4. if j value is not 1 then it goes to else part.
5. in this there are again if and else part in if part we use mod operator and if its value gives 0 value then print star otherwise goto else condition.

   ```
    for(int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
       for(int j = 1; j <= i * i; j++) {
           if(j == 1) {
               System.out.println();
               System.out.print("*");

           } else if(j % i == 0) {
               System.out.print("*");
               System.out.println();
           } else {
               System.out.print("*");
           }
       }
   }
   ```